# How to run react-scripts start from an express server?

Tags: reactjs, express

I'd like to run a react app served by an express server. Even though it's not the solution, the effect what I'd like to earn is `app.use("/", "react-scripts start")`, so if the server gets a request at `"/"`, it starts the react app, and serves it's files.

I read about the solution of building the app, and serve bundle.js, or just adding a proxy with the server's URL to the client app's package.json, but that's not what I want, and haven't found anything similar to the effect I'd like to earn.

I'm not sure what `react-scripts start` does, and how it's working, but the reason why I need it is that I don't want to restart the whole server, and wait until the app builds every time I change something in the front-end.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you're wanting to do is essentially reinventing the wheel... `react-scripts` and `create-react-app` already do this for you... Was your app built with `create-react-app`? If so, it comes with hot-reloading.. All you have to do is open a separate terminal/command prompt, then `cd /root/path/of/project` then `npm start` or if you're using `yarn` you can just do `yarn start`... After each change you make, your app will auto-reload...

Answer (score 6):

`react-scripts start` sets up the development environment and starts a server along with hot module reloading. Basically, create-react-app helps you kick off your project without going into the intricacies of WebPack configurations.

Run `react-scripts build` to build your project files into build folder & then, you can create a server.js file that uses Express to serve your build folder.

server.js

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, 'build');

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up!');
});
```

run `node server.js` to start your server.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly is the outcome you're trying to achieve?  Using `create-react-app` (for which `react-scripts` is a utility), or webpack in general, the app must *always* be rebuilt at some point for the changes to be seen, since JSX is not browser-compatible and must be transpiled to regular JS.  Also, it's not necessary to restart the server if you're only making changes to the front end.

Running `react-scripts start` basically runs [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) (WDS) which is built into CRA's configuration.  WDS does not actually build the project in the sense of outputting build files, but it still must build it in-memory to be able to even display the changes at all. On a normal application, rebuilding through WDS shouldn't take more than a handful of seconds, and that's about the fastest feedback loop you're going to get for seeing changes manifest.

If you're running an Express server alongside a CRA app, I'd recommend looking into [concurrently](https://www.google.com/search?q=npm+concurrently&oq=npm+concurrently&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2015j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), the former of which will allow you to run your server and React client with one command, and the latter of which will automatically restart your server for you (only when back end changes are made, a front end change will not trigger a server restart).